# Transit visa or air transit visa via London Heathrow

Tags: international-travel, residency

I am a research student from India working in European funding project in University of Pisa, Italy.

My Schengen visa will expire on Jan 8 2017. But I have scheduled to stay until February 8 2017 in Italy.

I am travelling from Pisa to Delhi via London Heathrow on February 8th 2017. Transit time of 2 hours 30 minutes before I catch the connecting flight via British airways. I don't even need to cross immigration area or leave the airport. Though my visa will expire, I still hold the valid residence permit issued by Italy until February. Having this card am I eligible to be exempted from needing a transit visa or air transit visa? I am using British Airways.

Comment: Your residence permit basically replaces the visa.  As long as one of them is valid, you can transit the UK without a visa.